# Http request and operating system

Tags: java, http, networking, operating-system

What are the steps that are executed in operating system, when we make a http call from higher level program like java, python. What all components are involved in making a http call?

As far as i understand, a blocking network connection will be made from client machine to server, and once server responds, an interrupt will be generated, to notify the calling thread.

But few things are still blackbox to me

1. how is http call different from lets say RPC call in terms of operating system interaction
2. Is connection reuse a property of operating system or application code. Let's say there are 2 clients running on 1 client machine, will they be able to reuse existing connection?
3. How is application thread notified once response from server is available for consumption.
4. Is there any difference b/w how programming languages handle this? let's say java vs python vs go.

Answer (score 1):

> how is http call different from lets say RPC call in terms of operating system interaction

They are not, since both are simply TCP/IP connections, as far as the OS is concerned.

> Is connection reuse a property of operating system or application code. Let's say there are 2 clients running on 1 client machine, will they be able to reuse existing connection?

Application code controls reuse.

> How is application thread notified once response from server is available for consumption.

The OS method call returns. Unless the OS support asynchronous calls. Answer depends on OS and what API method the application called.

> Is there in difference b/w how programming languages handle this? lets say java vs python vs go.

Yes. I mean, they pretty much do the same thing, i.e. implement the protocol according to the specification, but they have their own code for doing it.

Comment: is there any doc where i can read more about this?

Comment: @bestwishes [**Questions asking us to recommend or find a book**, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic** for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Do your own **research**.